# PyInstaller cannot be installed using pip

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

I was installing pyinstaller soo I can make a exe file.
But pyinstaller did not want to install.
Even with the lates version of pip and python Python310 (Install folder in C:)

Command: `pip install pyinstaller`

And same with py2exe and auto-py-to-exe.

My pc works normal. I have to convert it to a exe so I can finish my very own programming language Called Binpy (Or binary Python)

The folder contains

```
__pycache__
 app.cpython-310.pyc
Output
 BinPyInstaller.exe (Installer)
binpy.py (Main)
LICENSE.txt
logo.ico (256x256)
logo.png (512x512)
Norosoft.txt
setup.iss (Inno setup script, Not important and not included on the final build)
```

**MY PC RUNS WINDOWS 11. MAKE SURE THE ANSWER DOSE WORK WITN WINDOWS 11**

Error message

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Noros\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8iurdv5w\\pefile_e6b484235e2a483685550e298cd9fd50\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Noros\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8iurdv5w\\pefile_e6b484235e2a483685550e298cd9fd50\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Noros\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7ftz7nv1\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Python310\Include\pefile'
         cwd: C:\Users\Noros\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8iurdv5w\pefile_e6b484235e2a483685550e298cd9fd50\
    Complete output (14 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib
    copying pefile.py -> build\lib
    copying peutils.py -> build\lib
    creating build\lib\ordlookup
    copying ordlookup\oleaut32.py -> build\lib\ordlookup
    copying ordlookup\ws2_32.py -> build\lib\ordlookup
    copying ordlookup\__init__.py -> build\lib\ordlookup
    running install_lib
    byte-compiling C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pefile.py to pefile.cpython-310.pyc
    error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Python310\\Lib\\site-packages\\__pycache__\\pefile.cpython-310.pyc.2073893236656'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Noros\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8iurdv5w\\pefile_e6b484235e2a483685550e298cd9fd50\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Noros\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8iurdv5w\\pefile_e6b484235e2a483685550e298cd9fd50\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Noros\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7ftz7nv1\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Python310\Include\pefile' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I hope you have a fix to it!

Comment: Can you share the error that you get, the full traceback if possible

Comment: The error dosent fit in this comment as it is a package installation faliure i think

Comment: Don't add it as a comment, add it to the question

Comment: I have included the error message on the question

Comment: Try running your terminal as administrator (should be an option in the right-click menu), you don't have permission to write to site-packages

Comment: Thanks running adminstrator worked now i can now finish my project and release it to the public